# How to ask for `*://*/*` as optional_permissions addon

Tags: google-chrome-extension, permissions, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-webextensions, web-extension

I need to ask for `*://*/*` permission, but I don't know how to do this, because with `.permissions.require()` doesn't work.

Steps I followed:

- Insert `*://*/*` as "optional_permissions" in the manifest
- Use this code to try to ask for permission

  ```js
  const permissionsToRequest = {
                  permissions: ["*://*/*"]
              }

              async function onResponse(response) {
                  if (response) {
                      //Granted
                      console.log("Granted");
                  } else {
                      //Refused
                      console.log("Refused");
                  }
                  return browser.permissions.getAll();
              }

              console.log("Yes");
              browser.permissions.request(permissionsToRequest).then(onResponse);
  ```

I tried to use also “origins” but nothing… doesn’t work anyway

Comment: Use `origins:` instead of `permissions:`

Answer (score 0):

The problem was the "permissions". As a user suggested, the answer is to use "origins" instead